# Fresh install of Windows 10 killed SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I have a [laptop that came with Win 7](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834131178&Tpk=34-131-178) (the HDD is on SATA II).
About a year ago, I installed a Samsung 850 Evo 500GB (cloned the data from the HDD). It worked beautifully (always <5s boot time).
A few months later, I auto-upgraded to Win 10. Everything still worked great (as far as the SSD is concerned; obviously I had a few usual Win 10 headaches).

Two days ago, I wiped the drive (using a Secure Erase bootable CD made by Samsung Magician) and fresh installed Win 10 (1511 build). Now the entire machine is *sloow* (>1min boot time, frequent lagging, etc. -- nothing like the performance I've been seeing for the past year.) Updating all of the drivers did nothing to improve that.

I have wiped and reinstalled again, and it still didn't fix it. I am fairly sure that the drive is causing the problems; it mostly lags when the "drive access" light is illuminated.

I have found many pieces of advice discussing issues that can occur with SSDs and Windows 10; usually a fresh install is the solution, not the problem.

Additional info:

- In Task Manager, Disk is stuck at >95%, even with total I/O at less than 1MB/s.
- I used the same Samsung Magician Secure Erase and Windows Installer boot drives for another Win 10 install on another computer, and they both worked fine.
- In Samsung Magician performance test, seq. read is 553 MB/s and seq. write is 88 MB/s. I watched the Resource Monitor; Read never went over 1MB/s, but Write went up to 200MB/s. What is happening here?

Comment: have you tried checking which process is using the most disk time with resource monitor?

Comment: @Blaine Resource Monitor (as perfmon.exe) and System. Both only around 500KB/s. Looking at the drive and SATA II specs, 100% should be 3Gb/s...

Comment: hmm, certainty does sound like an issue with the ssd controler

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Kittsil I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on behalf of my own comments as well as OP's troubleshooting. The issue wound up being with the "OOD". OP also was helped by this thread [superuser.com/a/674120/596596](https://superuser.com/a/674120/596596).

When troubleshooting overall, make sure that you have isolated the problem to a specific component. Try a known working hard drive in the computer at fault, and try the hard drive from the faulty computer in a known working computer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some problem with windows setup, from which you are fresh installing windows 10. I recommend using Microsft's official windows setup tool to create windows 10 setup usb/dvd and install using that.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

Also make sure to download windows for correct architecture of your pc (32-bit or 64-bit).

P.S. I had used the pirated setup of windows 10 and it caused me same problem in my ssd. Go for official windows :).

Comment: I did use official Win 10 setup. I also used it on another computer with no problems. I should have said that, and will add it to the question now.

Comment: Have you tried other OS than windows 10 like Linux or windows 7/8.1 . If you still face the issue, then i must say, problem is hardware specific.

Comment: Thanks, that is good advice. I will try Linux next if I can't get it working this time.

Comment: try installing to a different hard drive if you can to see if it is in fact a problem with the hard drive (or use the same hdd in a different computer)

Comment: @Kittsil Oh good! What was the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I am going to offer two suggestions. First... don't use Samsung's erase tool. Boot the Windows 10 media and as part of a clean install delete all the partition on the drive from withing the setup procedure.

Secondly.... get build 1607. If you re-download the media creation tool and re-create the ISO it should be build 1607.

Comment: The author already figured out the problem.  They had a hardware problem.  Due to this fact, this answer, doesn't really answer the question.  Always important to check, if the question has already been solved, before  submitting generic advice like this.